# css selector for first list item

Tags: html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have the following html structure.

```
<ul>
  <script id="agendaTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
               <li class="arrow boundElement" style="height:40px;" onclick="GoToPage('session.html?session_id=${agenda_id}');">

                </li>
    </script>
 <li class="arrow boundElement" style="height:40px;" onclick="GoToPage('session.html?     session_id=2');"> test</li>
 <li class="arrow boundElement" style="height:40px;" onclick="GoToPage('session.html?     session_id=2');"> test</li>
</ul>
```

I need to apply class to the first li of the list. 
The script tag cannot be removed, coz it is a template for the structure. 
I tried with `ul > li:first-child` but it is not working. It works only if the li is the first child of the ul, i.e. if the script tag is not present.

Please suggest me a way to apply style to the first li of the ul.

Note: I am not allowed to add a new class to the first li.

Comment: "The script tag cannot be removed" Yes it can and yes it should. What you have is invalid html.

Comment: @Raghav , do you want that selected list item should be highlighted

Comment: @ RepWhoringPeeHaa : I know it can be removed technically. But am not allowed to. And i dont care if it is a valid html, coz it is generated by some plugin and i dont want to break any existing code.
@freebird: yeah. i need to apply corners to the first li. first-of-type seems to work for me.

Comment: @Raghav If you are not allowed to remove it there is something wrong within your organization. If this is added by a plugin, the plugin sucks big time and should be avoided at any cost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `first-of-type` instead:

```
ul > li:first-of-type
```

This is a CSS3 selector - so is not completely supported across older browsers. See @Boltclock's answer for much better cross-browser support

Comment: The browser support issue is especially important to note, as jQuery does not support `:first-of-type`.

Comment: with jquery this works for me $("ul > li:first-of-type") very well. But since am using it via, css, its okay if the above breaks.

Comment: U are right. It doesnt work in IE. But tats fine. We are targeting only mobile browsers which is rendered by html5.

Answer (score 2):

> It works only if the li is the first child of the ul, i.e. if the script tag is not present.

Exactly.

Since you're using a jQuery template, and you're trying to manipulate the first `li` to give it a class without modifying the HTML source, you may as well do this all with jQuery:

```
$('ul > li:first').addClass('first');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a trick for selecting all first items of adjacent lists of items:

```css
li:not(li + li) {
  background: #f00;
}

/* Or the more intuitive one: */
ul > :not(li) + li, ul > li:first-child {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <div></div>

 <li>I'm selected</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>

 <div></div>

 <li>I'm selected</li>
 <li>test</li>
</ul>
```